# Gray line in bottom of edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am developing an android application. I added some edit text to project but there is a problem. as you see in this [link](http://www.codeofaninja.com/2012/01/android-edittext-example.html), there is a gray line at the bottom of edit text and when we touch edit text, that line changes to blue.

but in my project, there is no gray line at the bottom of edit texts. what's wrong? How can I fix it?

thanks.

Comment: It depend on your theme.in older api edittext have white box but in newer theme layout change to this.you should change your theme

Comment: you mean that I should change application theme in manifest?

Comment: yes.if you change theme you can see change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use `@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light` as aplication theme you will see this

[image]

but if you use this `@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar`, you will see this:

[image]